# how to authenticate user in JAX-RS using apache CXF?

Tags: apache, security, cxf, jax-rs

I am using apache CXF for JAX-RS application.I followed the example in the url 'http://www.javatips.net/blog/2012/02/cxf-restful-tutorial'.....
Finally,I am hosting the application as 'war' in tomcat under 'webapps'?...

How to inject security(simple authorization and authentication) in JAX-RS?
Basically,my aim is to validate a 'user' role before catering service request?

Can anyone provide a neat example?

Answer (score 0):

i have no idea about CXF but you can find a Security in JAX-RS how to ? [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11136027/authentication-in-rest-jersey/13578820#13578820)
.

Comment: ok now give some detailed scenario for your case, i'll help you.

Comment: Yogesh..Please see my latest post in the <link>http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11343996/handle-authentication-and-authorization-in-jax-rs-webservice-with-cxf/13915417#13915417</link>